# Parsing non-JSON JavaScript object with Jackson

Tags: java, javascript, json, parsing, jackson

How can Jackson be made to parse the following JavaScript object?

```
{
  // this is a comment
  x: '1',
  y: {
    z: '2'
  }
}
```

Note that the example object above is not actual JSON—it is a JavaScript object which (1) doesn't have quotes around attribute names, (2) uses single, not double, quotes around values, and (3) contains a comment.

Use case: I need to parse a JavaScript object that is embedded in HTML. I can get the JavaScript object itself, but I now need to parse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with some [parser options](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParser.Feature.html):

```
private static final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);
om.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
om.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS, true);
```

Comment: +1, Of course all of these are parser features though.